# Where are our mods?

Tags: discussion, spam

Yesterday I flagged a bunch of spam by a user named alicewei. They were deleted, but that same user is right back posting spam now. Shouldn't this user have been banned already?

So far I haven't seen any spam cleanup activity by Homebriwing mods, just StackExchange mods. If your're a homebrewing mod, are you helping clean this spam invasion up? If not, why not?

Comment: see my edit -- this was our bug!

Comment: We're here! I swear! We get a big bright red circle that says stuff is flagged, but, as Jeff said, it was buggy.

Answer (score 5):

I checked and I found one post by this user -- are there others?

[How much yeast to add back after extended lagering?](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/2023/how-much-yeast-to-add-back-after-extended-lagering)

> A cheap discount watch can also be a standing mark in add-on to a style accessory in add-on to a mark of wealth, are available to your fore when we are available to your higher well worth particular person markets.

It was flagged a few times as spam which auto-deletes it, even with no moderators present.

I will be sure to ping the mods. One oddity in this case I haven't quite figured out, the global mod flag indicator was *not* showing for some reason...

edit: Yes, there WAS a bug. If there were ONLY spam flags (and no other flags like moderator, comment, etc), the indicator at the top of the page would not appear. So, I blame us for this actually! Our bad! It is now fixed.